# how to use a editable combobox like a dropdownlist in java?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I need to get what the user typed in the editable combo, and research and repopulate the compo accordind to the word. I am trying like this:

```
 JTextComponent editor = (JTextComponent) cb.getEditor().getEditorComponent();    

    editor.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
       public void keyReleased(KeyEvent evt) {
           atualizarCombo();
       }
    });
```

But when i try to get the value of the editable combo it gets only the first letter and all disapeers:

```
 static void atualizarCombo(){
    try {

        System.out.println("action");
        String typed = (String) cb.getEditor().getItem();

        newSelection  = typed;
        newSelection = newSelection.trim();
        carregarCombo(newSelection);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TesteCombo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner please post a valid [mcve] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/) (i.e. a full example code, that demonstrates the issue, that is short enough to be posted here and we can copy-paste w/o modifying it, it should include the imports and a main method too). Please take the [tour] and go through the [help], then learn [ask] a good question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is only getting the first value because you are using a keyListener.  Everytime a key is 'released' in this case your `keyReleased` method gets called.  I am not sure what your `carregarCombo` method is doing because you didn't post this code.  However I would use a [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/DocumentListener.html) instead of a keyListener

Comment: Actually getting the first value is not a problem with the KeyListener. The problem is somewhere else in the code (which is why the [mcve] should be posted). However, I agree you should be using a DocumentListener for this since it is a newer and better API. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Listening For Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for more information and a working example. So (1+) for this suggestion.

Comment: thank you a lot I used the documentlistener and it solved!